# LaTeX amsthm package - starting the 'section' number at 16

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I'm taking notes from a textbook via LaTeX (as a study guide / way to learn) and I'm starting on chapter 16. I want the theorems to say "Theorem 16.1, Theorem 16.2..." etc. I am using the basic syntax:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
```

and I'm wondering what I can replace section with.

Comment: setting the counter (as in the answer) is correct, but if you are starting on *chapter* 16, it seems that you should be using the `[chapter]` counter as the theorem option.  (confused? so am i.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks, meant to thank you a few months ago but school happened!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the `section` counter.    Use on your preamble

```
\setcounter{section}{15}
```

So when you start a new section with `\section{}` the counter will be increased by one.